# Proper design for an API to prevent public access when used with AJAX

Tags: ajax, rest, api, security, post

I am designing a small API for my app. My goal is to allow external domains to query the API using a POST request, which I anticipate will most commonly be performed via a client-side protocol like AJAX.

I would like to restrict access to my API to users I have pre-authorized, and I'm wondering how best to support this feature.

My first thought was to store a table of keys for my users. I would require that a key be provided when accessing my API; this key would be checked against my table of authorized keys during every API request, and the query would only execute if a match was found. But this wouldn't be secure: since most users would access my API via a client-side protocol like AJAX, their code would expose the key, which could be appropriated by a malicious user.

My second thought was to store a table of keys and referrers. Each authorized referrer would have its own unique key. When a user tried to access my API with their secret key, I would pull that user's HTTP_REFERER and check to ensure that the referring domain matched the key provided. However, this is also exploitable: a malicious user could easily use cUrl to spoof a referrer and exploit the system.

Is there any way to construct a secure API that can only be accessed by authorized users, but is accessed via a client-side protocol like AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to construct a secure API that can only be accessed by authorized users, but is accessed via a client-side protocol like AJAX?

The short answer is NO, assuming you mean only calls made from JavaScript code.

Anything that runs on the client side and needs some secret to access an API is doomed to be abused in several ways. You already mentioned some and you can read about some more on [this series of articles](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) about mobile api security techniques. This articles will teach you how API Keys, User Access Tokens, HMAC, TLS Pinning can be used to protect the API and how they can be bypassed. The articles are more in the context of an API for a mobile app but they are good to illustrate you why you cannot protect your API from AJAX calls.

If you need to make these calls from a mobile app then the reply would be YES, provided you use the appropriated measures, that I will not detail here because it seems your app is not a mobile app. If it is a mobile please let me know in the comments and I will edit the response to explain what are the measures you can apply.

Comment: Thank you! This is a bummer for my app but makes sense.